# How to understand the Cartesian product of two fields?

Tags: field-theory

So I'm a first year just starting analysis and linear algebra and so far, I suck. I'm not sure how to understand, or more so, interpret everything.

So here are my questions:

1) So the elements of the cartesian product of two fields would be in the form $(x, y)$. So I'm confused. Somewhere I saw that $(1,0)$ is the multiplicative identity, but shouldn't $(1, 1)$ be a multiplicative identity? Why isn't $(0, 1)$ the multiplicative identity then?

2) So some Cartesian products of fields are not fields and some are.
For example: the complex numbers, they are a field.
However, the reason why some cartesian products of fields are not fields is because $(1, 0)$ must an element of the Cartesian product but since it doesn't have an multiplicative inverse, it fails to satisfy Field Axiom 4b. However, the complex numbers have an equivalent of $(1, 0)$ but its still considered a field. I may be wrong about something here but can anyone explain? Also, doesn't the Field Axiom fail for $(0, 1)$ as well? Or is it that the x part can't equal to zero so only $(1,0)$ is something that should be tested?

I might have others but I don't really know enough to know what I don't know yet. I apologize if these questions are very trivial but I can't quite wrap my head around it and I looked at other sources but no such luck.

Thank you!

Comment: The cartesian product of two fields is not a field, since $(1,0)\cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$. $\Bbb C$ is a field, but not arising as the product $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$. Subtle difference.

Answer (score 5):

$(1,0)$ isn't a multiplicative identity because it doesn't work.  For instance, $(1,0) \cdot (0,1) = (0,0)$, not $(0,1)$.

Direct products of fields are never fields (if you require $0 \neq 1$ for a field, which most sensible people do.)  The reasons are plentiful:  zero divisors will exist and not everyone is invertible.

Your confusion might lie here: $\mathbb{C}$ may be thought of as $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ either as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or as a topological space.  In these senses it IS a cross product, but it is NOT so as a ring.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Randall's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2439760/608978) is fine, but I would like to provide a more detailed answer that I believe may help with some underlying misunderstood concepts.

## Fields

Let us remember that a field $\mathbb{F}$ actually consists of three things

- A set which I will denote $\mathcal{A}$.
- An additive operation $+$ which tells us how to sum elements of $\mathcal{A}$.
- A multiplication operation $*$ that tells us how to multiply elements of $\mathcal{A}$.

And this set along these operations must follow the axioms which I believe you are familiar with.

Usually people use the same notation for the field $\mathbb{F}$ and the set $\mathcal{A}$, and often the operations are implicitly assumed to be some natural operations. I believe this is leading to some confusion as we will see below.

## Cartesian Product

A cartesian product builds a **set** from two other **sets**. If we have two sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, it tells us how to construct a new set $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$, with elements of the form $(a, b), a \in \mathcal{A}, b \in \mathcal{B}$. However, it does not act on **fields**. It does not let us know how to add or multiply elements of this new set $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$.

A very natural way to define such operations would be the element-wise operations, where $(a_1, b_1) + (a_2, b_2) = (a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)$ and $(a_1, b_1) * (a_2, b_2) = (a_1 * b_1, a_2 * b_2)$, where the addition and multiplication are defined according to the underlying original fields. **If we use these operations, what we have just defined is not a field**. The easiest way to see it is that the multiplicative identity would be $(1_a, 1_b)$, as you correctly indicated, where $1_a$ and $1_b$ are the multiplicative identities of the original fields, however, any elements of the form $(0_a, b)$ and $(a, 0_b)$, where again $0_a$ and $0_b$ are the additive identities of the original fields, do not have a multiplicative inverse.

## Complex Numbers

You can think of the set of complex numbers as the cartesian product of two sets of real numbers. However, when we multiply complex numbers, it is **not** the element-wise multiplication we defined above. We actually define the multiplication of two complex numbers as $(a, b) * (c, d) = (ac - bd, bc + ad)$. This is why $(1, 0)$ is the multiplicative identity, not $(1, 1)$. Using **this specific multiplication definition** for the cartesian product allows it to be a field.

## TL;DR

Whether something is a field or not depends not only on the set of elements, but also on how you define addition and multiplication. The set consisting of the cartesian product of two sets of real numbers may or may not be a field, depending on how you define the operations. If you define it to match how we multiply complex numbers naturally, then it is a field, and the multiplicative identity is $(1, 0)$.